# Rewrite rule regex help required

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, regex

Hoping you can help with this...

WE have a 'serivces' custom post type that allows a 'service' to have a parent 'service'.  Our custom rewrite rule works for top-level services but not child services.

The url structure would be something like the following where 'test-service' and 'test-service-child' are the post names:

1. consultancy/test-service
2. consultancy/test-service/test-service-child

Our existing rewrite rule is as follows:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^consultancy/(.*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=service&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Can anyone suggest a modification that will get the post name from the end of the url?  Eg in the case of the examples above it should match the following

1. test-service
2. test-service-child

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance,

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our custom rewrite rule works for top-level services but not child
> services.

Your rewrite rule, or the query (the **second** parameter for `add_rewrite_rule()`) is just missing a `service` query:

```php
add_rewrite_rule( // wrapped for brevity
    '^consultancy/(.*)/?',

    // Here, add the &service=$matches[1]
    'index.php?post_type=service&name=$matches[1]&service=$matches[1]',

    'top'
);
```

But, why don't you just use `consultancy` as the rewrite [`slug`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters) when you register the post type?

```php
register_post_type( 'service', [
    'public'       => true,
    'rewrite'      => [ 'slug' => 'consultancy' ],
    'hierarchical' => true,
    // .. other args here.
] );
```

That way, you wouldn't need the custom rewrite rule because the above `'slug' => 'consultancy'` will set the permalink structure for your "service" posts to `consultancy/<post name/slug>`.

> Can anyone suggest a modification that will get the post name from the
> end of the URL?

You can use:

- `get_query_var( 'service' )` or `get_query_var( 'name' )` to get the *complete* post name/slug *path* from the current URL.

  So if the URL is `https://example.com/consultancy/test-service/test-service-child`, you'd get `test-service/test-service-child`.
- `get_queried_object()->post_name` to get the actual post name/slug for the queried post, i.e. without the parent path.

  So if the URL is `https://example.com/consultancy/test-service/test-service-child`, `get_queried_object()->post_name` would return `test-service-child` (note the `child`).

Comment: That's wonderful, works perfectly.  Thank you.  In answer to your question re using Consultancy as the slug - that bit is actually dynamic as each service falls under one of a list of Sectors so we're having to do this:  
`$service_sectors = indigo_get_service_sectors();
  
foreach ($service_sectors as $key => $value) {  
 add_rewrite_rule('^'.$key.'/(.*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=service&name=$matches[1]&service=$matches[1]', 'top');  
}`